Other, easier, approaches to proving: for $k$ coprime integers summing to zero, there is no bound on $\min\{\Omega(a_1),\ldots,\Omega(a_k)\}$
I put this on Stackexchange, and the question was closed without them specifying why (they just said "no context", even though I did mention the context). Never mind - I have deleted the question from there.
Some Reddit user asked this. I thought about it for half a day and came up with an solution.
My main query is whether you can think of more elementary solutions, which don't use analytic number theory. I myself have never studied the latter, I just happen to know the statements of the main theorems. I added the tag "additive combinatorics", which again I've never studied.
Problem
Fix $k>2$. Range over all possible choices of $a_1,\ldots,a_k$ such that they are coprime integers (some positive, some negative, none of them being $\pm1$) that add to zero. Is there an upper bound on $\min\{\Omega(a_1),\ldots,\Omega(a_k)\}$?
$\Omega$ counts prime factors with multiplicity.
(I just realised: the coprime condition is stronger than what the Redditor asked for. But anyway.)
My solution (with spoiler effect)

 The answer is no.  Fix $N$. The integers with at most $N$ prime factors have an asymptotic density of zero. By the way, I call such a number an $N$-adprime.  Fix $k$. What we would like to do is to start with an example of $k$ coprime integers (some positive, some negative) that sum to zero. Let's call this condition exactness.   Then, what we're going to do is to turn the example $c_1,\ldots,c_k$ into something like $c_1+xn,c_2+xn,\ldots,c_{k-1}+xn,c_k-(k-1)xn$, where $x$ is a constant that we will select judiciously and $n$ ranges over the positive integers. We'll choose $x$ so that this new set is guaranteed to be exact for all but finitely many $n$, and also so that $x>\max\{c_1,\ldots,c_{k-1}\}-\min\{c_1,\ldots,c_{k-1}\}$.  As $n$ increases, what if every one of these sets had an $N$-adprime? It would mean that the upper asymptotic density of $N$-adprimes would be at least $\dfrac{1}{2(k-1)x}$. Contradiction.  As for how to choose $x$:  You want $\gcd(c_1+xn,c_2+xn)=\gcd(c_1+xn,c_2-c_1)$ to be equal to $1$. Wouldn't it be nice if $(c_2-c_1)$ divides $x$? If you can arrange that, then the calculation continues as $\gcd(c_1+xn,c_2-c_1)=\gcd(c_1,c_2-c_1)=\gcd(c_1,c_2)=1$.  Also, you want $\gcd(c_1+xn,c_k-(k-1)xn)=\gcd(c_1+xn,c_k+(k-1)c_1)$ to be equal to $1$. Wouldn't it be nice if $(c_k+(k-1)c_1)$ divides $x$?  Therefore, the criterion should be that $x$ be a multiple of $\displaystyle\prod_{u<w<k}(c_w-c_u)(c_k+(k-1)c_w)$.  As for how to find an example of an exact set of $k$ integers in the first place:  Make use of the fact that for $j$ large enough, $p_{j+k}-p_{j+1}<p_{j+1}$. (I use $p_w$ to denote the $w^\text{th}$ prime.) This is a corollary of the prime number theorem.  Also, for any positive integer $V\geq7$, you can find a pair of positive coprime integers $v_1,v_2>1$ that sum to $V$. (Exercise.)  Again, for $k=2l+2$, we can choose $p_{j+1}-p_{j+2}+p_{j+3}-p_{j+4}+\cdots+p_{j+2l-1}-p_{j+2l}+v_1+v_2=0$. Notice that $v_1+v_2<p_{j+2l}-p_{j+1}<p_{j+k}-p_{j+1}<p_{j+1}$ so there is no sharing of factors.  Again, for $k=2l+1$, we can choose $p_{j+1}-p_{j+2}+p_{j+3}-p_{j+4}+\cdots+p_{j+2l-1}-p_{j+2l}+V=0$.


Yes, pick $a_3,a_4,\ldots,a_k$ odd coprime integers, with $\Omega(a_i)\ge N$. Let $Q$ be the set of prime divisors of $a_3,\ldots,a_k$ and $a_3+\ldots+a_k$. Pick $2N$ primes $p_1,\ldots,p_{2N}\notin Q$.
By the Chinese Remainder theorem, we can find $x \in\mathbb Z$ such that
\begin{align}
x & \equiv 0\pmod{p_1\ldots p_N} \\
x + a_3+\ldots + a_k & \equiv 0 \pmod{p_{N+1}\ldots p_{2N}} \\
x & \not\equiv 0 \pmod q \\
x + a_3+\ldots + a_k & \not\equiv 0 \pmod q
\end{align}
for all $q\in Q$. (For $q\ge 3$, there is at least one residue left for the two last condition. We need to be careful about $q=2$. We have $2\in Q$ only if $a_3+\ldots+a_k$ is even. In that case we take $x$ odd.)
We take $a_1=x$ and $a_2=-(x+a_3+\ldots+a_k)$.

Quelque part sur ce site (ou sur StackEx) on raconte l'histoire d'une équation dont les auteurs d'un article ont prouvé - à travers des méthodes très compliquées dans la théorie des courbes elliptiques - qu'elle n'admet pas de solution entière. Puis, quelqu'un d'autre a publié dans le même journal une petite remarque selon laquelle modulo un certain premier elle n'a pas de solution non plus. N'ayant pas songé à cette approche beaucoup plus directe, je ressens presque de l'embarras LOLOL
